# Get a part of a folder name as variable

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting, shared-folders

I have 2 folders names that have 2 ids like "ABFD00" and "KASD02".

Now I need a little part of the folder as a variable (00 and 02) to use it in a command.
 Like:

```
sapcontrol -nr $sid -function GetSystemInstanceList
```

Comment: Welcome to the site. It seems you are using these commands inside a shell script. Can you post a larger excerpt of this script, which includes the point where you read in the folder names you want to manipulate?

Comment: Where and how does that "little part of the folder" show up in your command?

Comment: I don't know how to get this part of the folder. I need this part for the command. $sid is the variable for one ID.

Comment: What is the full directory name and where is it kept (in a variable?), and what does your command have to do with it?

Answer (score 3):

You can assign the output to a variable, then you can use pattern matching, for example:

```
VAR1=ABCD01
echo ${VAR1##*[[:alpha:]]}
```

This will remove all alphabetical characters from the variable and will print "01".

Comment: are you sure about that? `VAR1=ABCD01; echo ${VAR1#[[:alpha:]]}`
output `BCD01`

Comment: updated it properly - added * after another #. It should work now.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
$ find . -name "[A-Z]*" -type d | 
while read FN
  do    echo  sapcontrol -nr ${FN##*[A-Z]} -function GetSystemInstanceList 
  done
sapcontrol -nr 00 -function GetSystemInstanceList
sapcontrol -nr 02 -function GetSystemInstanceList
```

Comment: With only two directories to process, One would think that find is an overkill, but  hey find is still an option :-)

Answer (score 2):

If it is only the last two characters you need from a few specific folders then there is also:

```
echo ${VAR1:(-2)}
```

or even (expanding on @RudiC) and choosing directories without any numerics except as the last two digits with GNU extended `find`

```
find . -type d -regex "[^0-9]*[0-9][0-9]" -exec sh -c 'echo sapcontrol -nr ${1:(-2)} -function GetSystemInstanceList' sh {} \;
```